# Inertia/Bisection Method for finding methods

Tags: python, computer-science, linear-programming

I want binsF to make sure each bin has only 1 eigenvalue of A. If an initial bin does not have eigenvalue get rid of it, and if a bin has 2 eigen values separate them by bisecting the bins. Do 4 steps of bisection to reduce the size of the bins.

```
def bins0(A):
    # Get the number of rows in A
    n = A.shape[0]

    # Initialize arrays to store the centers and radii of the Gerchgorin disks
    centers = np.zeros(n)
    radii = np.zeros(n)

    # Compute the centers and radii of the Gerchgorin disks
    for i in range(n):
        centers[i] = np.real(A[i, i])
        radii[i] = np.sum(np.abs(A[i, :])) - np.abs(A[i, i])

    # Compute the minimum and m
    # aximum eigenvalue bounds
    min = np.min(centers - radii)
    max = np.max(centers + radii)
    print(min, max)

    bins = np.zeros((n, 2))
    width = (max-min)/n

    for i in range(0, n):
        bins[i, 0] = min + (i * width)
        bins[i, 1] = min + ((i+1) * width)

   return bins

def binsF(A, nSteps):
    n = len(A)
    bins = bins0(A)
    new_bins = np.zeros((n, 2))

    for i in range(len(bins)):
     a = bins[i, 0]
     b = bins[i, 1]
     width = b-a

     for j in range(nSteps):
         t = (a+b)/2
         B = A-(t*np.eye(n))
         L, D, _ = lalg.ldl(B)
         neig = 0 

         for k in range(len(D)):
             if(D[k, k] < 0):
                 neig = neig + 1

         if neig > 0 and neig < len(A):
             if neig <= len(A) / 2:
                 b = t
             else:
                 a = t
                
         width = b - a
     new_bins[i, 0] = a
     new_bins[i, 1] = b

  return new_bins
```